# sum of hyperbolic sine and hyperbolic tangent

Tags: hyperbolic-functions

Can anyone have idea how to proof the following relationship?
\begin{equation}
\sum_{j=1}^N \frac{\sinh(T-\tau j) + \sinh(\tau j)}{\sinh(T)} = \frac{\tanh(0.5T)}{\tanh(0.5\tau)}, \qquad \text{as}~N\rightarrow\infty,
\end{equation}
where $\tau:=T/N$.

Many thanks!

Comment: *Hint*: Recall $\sum_1^N\sinh(x+ny)=\dfrac{\sinh(Ny/2)\sinh(x+(N+1)y/2)}{\sinh(y/2)}$.

Comment: thank you  user10354138, could you give me a hint about how to prove $\sum_{1}^N \sinh(x+ny)$?

Comment: This is just summing two geometric series, or you can multiply by $\sinh(y/2)$ and note that $2\sinh(A)\sinh(B)=\cosh(A+B)-\cosh(A-B)$, or Osborne's rule, or ...

Comment: Many thanks!  user10354138